# form textbox data getting cleared without validation on php

Tags: php

Notice inside textbox : Notice:  Undefined index: course in D:\xampp\htdocs\jobseeker\resumejobseeker.php on line 324

```
<label>Other Course/Diploma: </label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['course']); ?>" name="course"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?php echo isset($_POST['course']) ? htmlentities($_POST['course']) : ''; ?>
```

Reason:

Actually when the form is loaded for the 1st time there is no `post request` to the page and hence `$_POST['course']` is undefined; So you need to put blank in the `value` of the textbox (using the ternary operator here).

So the complete code is as follows:

```
<label>Other Course/Diploma: </label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['course']) ? htmlentities($_POST['course']) : ''; ?>" name="course"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**From the vast wisdom of the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):**

> Relying on the default value of an
>   uninitialized variable is problematic
>   in the case of including one file into
>   another which uses the same variable
>   name. It is also a major [security risk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)
>   with [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) turned on.
>   [E_NOTICE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-notice) level error is issued in case
>   of working with uninitialized
>   variables, however not in the case of
>   appending elements to the
>   uninitialized array. [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) language
>   construct can be used to detect if a
>   variable has been already initialized.

#### Some explanations:

Although PHP does not require variable declaration, it does recommend it in order to avoid some security vulnerabilities or bugs where one would forget to give a value to a variable that he will use later in the script. What PHP does in the case of undeclared variables is issue a very low level error, E_NOTICE, one that is not even reported by default, but the Manual [advises to allow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) during development.

#### Ways to deal with the issue:

1. **Recommended:** Declare your variables. Or use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  to check if they are declared before referencing them.
2. Set a [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) for E_NOTICE and redirect the messages away from the standard output (maybe to a log file). `set_error_handler('myHandlerForMinorErrors', E_NOTICE | E_STRICT)`.
3. Disable E_NOTICE from reporting. A quick way to exclude just E_NOTICE is `error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE )`.
4. Suppress the error with the [@ operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

**Note:** It's strongly recommended to implement just point *1.*

Related:

- [Notice: Undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12778634#12778634)
- [Notice: Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836)